# Outlook 2003 crashes when opening certain emails

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook, microsoft-office

Outlook crashes on certain emails

We are using Outlook 2003 with an exchange server. One users Outlook keeps on crashing when certain email comes in but it is not just off one person. I have ran a repair of the outlook file, I have turned off any addins and antivirus software. I have looked on Google but cannot find any answer to this. The error is

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source: Microsoft Office 11
Event Category: None
Event ID: 1000
Date:  11/06/2012
Time:  15:12:51
User:  N/A
Computer: ACER-4532DF3AFB
Description:
The description for Event ID ( 1000 ) in Source ( Microsoft Office 11 ) cannot be
found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message 
DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the
/AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details.
The following information is part of the event: outlook.exe, 11.0.8326.0, 4c1c2372,
mshtml.dll, 8.0.6001.19222, 4f4f570d, 0, 00003233.
Data:
0000: 41 00 70 00 70 00 6c 00   A.p.p.l.
0008: 69 00 63 00 61 00 74 00   i.c.a.t.
0010: 69 00 6f 00 6e 00 20 00   i.o.n. .
0018: 46 00 61 00 69 00 6c 00   F.a.i.l.
0020: 75 00 72 00 65 00 20 00   u.r.e. .
0028: 20 00 6f 00 75 00 74 00    .o.u.t.
0030: 6c 00 6f 00 6f 00 6b 00   l.o.o.k.
0038: 2e 00 65 00 78 00 65 00   ..e.x.e.
0040: 20 00 31 00 31 00 2e 00    .1.1...
0048: 30 00 2e 00 38 00 33 00   0...8.3.
0050: 32 00 36 00 2e 00 30 00   2.6...0.
0058: 20 00 34 00 63 00 31 00    .4.c.1.
0060: 63 00 32 00 33 00 37 00   c.2.3.7.
0068: 32 00 20 00 69 00 6e 00   2. .i.n.
0070: 20 00 6d 00 73 00 68 00    .m.s.h.
0078: 74 00 6d 00 6c 00 2e 00   t.m.l...
0080: 64 00 6c 00 6c 00 20 00   d.l.l. .
0088: 38 00 2e 00 30 00 2e 00   8...0...
0090: 36 00 30 00 30 00 31 00   6.0.0.1.
0098: 2e 00 31 00 39 00 32 00   ..1.9.2.
00a0: 32 00 32 00 20 00 34 00   2.2. .4.
00a8: 66 00 34 00 66 00 35 00   f.4.f.5.
00b0: 37 00 30 00 64 00 20 00   7.0.d. .
00b8: 66 00 44 00 65 00 62 00   f.D.e.b.
00c0: 75 00 67 00 20 00 30 00   u.g. .0.
00c8: 20 00 61 00 74 00 20 00    .a.t. .
00d0: 6f 00 66 00 66 00 73 00   o.f.f.s.
00d8: 65 00 74 00 20 00 30 00   e.t. .0.
00e0: 30 00 30 00 30 00 33 00   0.0.0.3.
00e8: 32 00 33 00 33 00 0d 00   2.3.3...
00f0: 0a 00                     ..
```

When I open the email via web access it opens okay.

Comment: When you say that you have run a repair on the outlook file, do you mean that you have repaired the Microsoft Office installation? or just fun a repair on the PST file for the profile?

Comment: Office 2003 is now 9 years old; it's mainstream support ended 3 years ago. Crashes like this are likely to become a common problem if you choose to continue to use outdated software.

Answer (score 0):

Turned all addons off, reinstalled Outlook, tested profile on another machine and it was okay, retested on new Outlook install and working okay.